# MAUI: which one to use between Task.Run, Worker and Foreground service when I want to run a periodic process?

Tags: android, maui

I have an Android application that is developped with MAUI.

I want to run a proecss in the backgroud of the application that check periocally the location, every 5 minutes for example, and send a notification according to some condition. A notification or alarm o sound.

I would like to run this process also when the device reboot or power on, always that the user has setted that the application can auto start.

Also I would like to run this process no matter if the application is closed or is not in the foregound, I mean, if the device is in the desktop screen, locked or running another application.

I am reading that to run a process in the background, I can use a Task.Run (this is cross-platform solution), a Worker or a Foreground Service.This two last options are Android specfic solution.

But I don't find a clear information that explains when to use each solution, or at least I don't understand well.

For me, it seems that the easiest solution it is to create a task that is a infinite while loop, with the logic that I need and wait the requiered time. But this solution is part of the application, so I don't know if it will keep running althoung the application is closed. or if it will run if the application is not in the foreground.

In summary, I would like to know the difference between the different solutions and which it would be the best option for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further reading after your "I would like to run this process no matter if the application is closed or is not in the foregound" go for Foreground service you have no other options really, as Background service is too restrictive and Foreground service is 100% fine.